# How to format sqlite results from python script?

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import csv,sqlite3
#opens connections/creates database
conn = sqlite3.connect('serpin.db')

c = conn.cursor()
#this is done to avoid "table already exists" error when creating table
try:
   c.execute("""CREATE TABLE Gene (Gene_name TEXT, Organism TEXT, link_2_gene_with_ID TEXT, Number_SpliceForm INTEGER,ID_mRNA INTEGER, ID_Prt INTEGER);""")
except:
   pass
#this is to import the csv file with correct column headers
path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\sqlite\practice.csv'
with open(path,'r') as fin: # `with` statement available in 2.5+
    # csv.DictReader uses first line in file for column headings by default
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin) # comma is default delimiter
    to_db = [(i['Gene_name'], i['Organism'],i['link_2_gene_with_ID'],i['Number_SpliceForm'],i['ID_mRNA'],i['ID_Prt'] ) for i in dr]
#inserts into Gene table
c.executemany("INSERT INTO Gene (Gene_name,Organism,link_2_gene_with_ID,Number_SpliceForm,ID_mRNA,ID_Prt) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?);", to_db)
#prints table
c.execute("select * from Gene;")
#prints table onto terminal
print(c.fetchall())
#commits changes
conn.commit()
#closes connection to database
conn.close
```

When I run this code, it formats the output in an odd manner:

```
[('Serpin28B', 'Dmel', 'http://flybase.org/reports/FBgn008314', '', '', ''), ('Serpin28Da', 'Dmel', 'http://flybase.org/reports/FBgn0051902', '', '', ''), ('Serpin28Db', 'Dmel', 'http://flybase.org/reports/FBgn0053121', '', '', ''), ('Serpin28F', 'Dmel', 'http://flybase.org/reports/FBgn0028987', '', '', ''), ('Serpin31A', 'Dmel', 'http://flybase.org/reports/FBgn0032178', '', '', ''), ('Serpin43Ab', 'Dmel', 'http://flybase.org/reports/FBgn0024293', '', '', ''), ('Serpin88Eb', 'Dmel', 'http://flybase.org/reports/FBgn0038299', '', '', ''),
```

I wanted to know how I could go about making it so the output is in a traditional table format i.e. with headers and clearly separated columns and rows. One more question; this code does not produce a serpin.db file in my folder, so I was wondering how I could make it create an actual file, as right now I have no idea where this data is being stored, so if I run the code more than once, the output is just a mess of repeated entries with no clear way of me cleaning it up.

Answer (score 0):

Just you neet to store the results in any vairable while doing `var=c.Fetchall()`
And run a for loop for printing it out

```
for i in var:
    Print (i)
```

This will be fine i think so

Comment: Hmm that does print out the results more neatly, but it is still missing the headers. Thanks for the help